# How do I get historical tweet with their location inclusive

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

How do I scrape historical tweet from twitter with their location inclusive

I was able to get tweets with their location using the tweeter API, but it doesn't go beyond a certain period. How do I get historical tweets with their location inclusive using a hashtag.

I saw this code from github which I could get historical tweets but I've been unable to modify it to get the location of the tweets.Also how do I get the parameters passed into the xpath and css methods. How do I modify the code to get the location of my tweets historical.

the tweet crawler I'm using is from : https://github.com/jonbakerfish/TweetScraper/blob/master/TweetScraper/spiders/TweetCrawler.py

Advice on any other way I have use to get it will be apprecaited